# STM32F4 bugs in DMA, is there bug-free version?

Tags: stm32, dma, fault, ahb

Producer has confirmed that if there will be concurrent AHB and APB2 transfers using DMA2, then data corruption will occur ([source](https://blog.frankvh.com/2012/01/13/stm32f2xx-stm32f4xx-dma-maximum-transactions/)). The bug discovery is from 2012, many years ago. Is the STM32F4 fixed now? It probably has some new revision, is there some pattern that allows to search for chip revisions with Google?

Comment: Have you had a look at the errata sheet?

Comment: Best would be to contact the manufacturer itself.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Thanks, looked at the errata sheet and there's only workaround given "don't concurrently use ABP and AHB", no information about a fix

Comment: @Gortu: So since the manufacturer has not mentioned a fix, you ask random people on the interwebs?

Comment: I read the errata now, not earlier. There are some revisions given, this could mean other revisions have no problems, but no mention on that, I think it's worth asking how to effectively track revisions and bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [errata](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/errata_sheet/0a/98/58/84/86/b6/47/a2/DM00037591.pdf/files/DM00037591.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00037591.pdf) that I found there are two basic revisions of the chip - "A" and "The Others" (not quite sure how they have so many second revisions, but that's ST's poor documentation for you). In neither revision is the problem fixed:

[image]